# Google analytics custom referal codes

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

We target is to view conversion reports based on traffic source, but google analytics show me only macro sources of traffic - like Facebook, Youtube, direct and so on. 
But i need more details.
I give different links to different facebook communities, for example:
https://imbahase.com/?c=facebook_community1
or
https://imbahase.com/?c=facebook_community2

If user registers on my site i save his refferal code(facebook_community1, facebook_community2 and so on) to my database.

The problem i met is that i need to view conversion reports filtered by referral code, to decide which publics converts better then another. How should i pass this data to google, and how to build reports i descrived higher?

I am currently using google tag manager and google analytics

**UPDATE. SOLUTION I WAS LOOKING FOR:**

Actually my tracking code is nearly same as campaigns in google analytics, so all i need is to get query string and do smth like

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', trackingCode);
ga('set', 'campaignSource', trackingCode);
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', trackingCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is register this as a custom dimension when the pageview is captured.

You have two options:

1. Use Google Tag Manager, and a Macro to capture the query string. When you fire the UA Pageview tag - add this captured variable into the Custom Dimension box.
2. Using JavaScript to capture the querystring from the url (http://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/) you can send it with your pageview like this:

   ga('send', 'pageview', {'dimension1':  query_string});